# How to overwrite a Polymer content scripts function

Tags: javascript, polymer, browser-console, shady-dom

I been trying to understand what part of code on youtube.com does redirect you to another site when clicking on a link in the description. For that I have tried to prevent all events to run in relation to the clicked element, but that does not help:

```
Object.keys(window).filter(
  k => /(?=^on)(?!.*move)(?!.*pointerup)(?!.*auxclick)/.test(k)
).forEach(key => {
  et.addEventListener(key.slice(2), ex => {
    console.log(`stop: ${key}`)
    ex.stopPropagation()
    ex.preventDefault()
  })
})
```

So I went to the browser console and checked which function is called when the button is pressed. However, when I try to call this function from the debugger, I get `x is not defined'.

Can someone explain why these functions are not accessible, and it's not possible to overwrite them, even from an extension code using a content script?

Comment: the function returns undefined.... normal behavior for a function that doesn't need to return anything? also I guess you'd have to prevent their event listener from ever being added (spoof event listening before the site loads)

Comment: But if you spoof it before the site is being loaded then the site's code will overwrite it. Also I have tried to prevent it from being loaded by overwriting the function code (before end of html tag) but it does not seem to help. I guess it is some new youtube shenanigans as the above code has been working before.

Comment: Polymer is using [shadow dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM), i.e. tiny isolated DOMs inside the DOM.

Comment: @siery not exactly true, when done right, you can mess up the environment for future scripts (aka the browser scripts)

Comment: @TheBombSquad, yes, you can overwrite base javascript. All though it's not guaranteed to not be overwriten later on. Although, I been talking about the functions defined by the developer. Rickard have pretty much answered my question, despite it's [Shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/shadydom) not Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can hijack the `addEventListener` function itself, you can find its source from `window.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` which contains `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener` and `dispatchEvent`

Paste the following code in a youtube tab's *inspect element console*; no event listeners would be added, neither would any of the globals you referenced be useful and the tab that this code would open, while technically youtube would be **VERY BROKEN**

**EDIT**: `addEventListener` is modified to do default behaviour for everything **except** `click` events

```js
function execute(){
  const eventClass=window.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
  const realListener=eventClass.addEventListener
  eventClass.addEventListener=function(){
    if(arguments[0]!=="click")  realListener.bind(this)(...arguments);
  }

  //now for modification of your code
  Object.keys(window).filter(
    k => /(?=^on)(?!.*move)(?!.*pointerup)(?!.*auxclick)/.test(k)
  ).forEach(function(key){
    const event=key.substr(2)
    realListener.bind(window)(key.slice(2), ex => {
      console.log(`stop: ${key}`)
      ex.stopPropagation()
      ex.preventDefault()
    })
    let dummy=null
    Object.defineProperty(window,key,{get:_=>dummy,set:thing=>dummy=thing})
  })
}
let myWindow=window.open(location.href)
myWindow.eval(`(${execute.toString()})()`)
```

Comment: Yes, I get that. But I don't want to brake the website just block a single event. For that I need to find a way to modify Polymer's Shady DOM.

Comment: * In spite of, this answer may be useful to someone new to javascript so I give it thumbs up.